# ANN Shape for Sale Prediction

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, layer, prediction, biological-neural-network

The inputs (features) and expected output for my ANN are these:

- Input 1: Product id (number, cast to double)
- Input 2: Year in the past (1900..2017, cast to double)
- Input 3: Month of year (1..12, cast to double)
- Expected output: Sale of month (number of units sold, cast to double)

I need to predict the sale of a product for a certain month in a certain year. **How many layers and how many neurons on there layers should I put**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one suggestion in here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/ann-shape-for-sale-prediction

But I finally implemented the network as LMS (least mean square) neural network with:

- 4 inputs
- 9 neurons in hidden layer
- 1 neuron in output layer

And instead of using 3 feature inputs, I use the sale of 4 previous months of a product as input. The prediction curve is rather flat than it's supposed to be but at least it is working.